# Geodjango- Can't get point in a polygon

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango

I have a model which is based on a shapefile:

My model is:
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models

```
class RegionBorder(models.Model):

    region_code = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=27700)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name
```

I've successfully imported the polygons into my database:

```
len(RegionBorder.objects.all())
9
```

But when I try to find a point within the polygons, I get nothing back. I know the point must be in the polygon as they're maps of the regions of England and I'm trying to find Nelsons column bang in the middle of London.

```
p = GEOSGeometry("Point(-0.127907 51.507786)", srid=27700)

RegionBorder.objects.filter(mpoly__contains=p)
[]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've swapped the co-ordinates just in case I had them the wrong way round, I've removed the srid arguments and started again. This is my first time doing any GIS stuff so I'm completely lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the wrong SRID for the points. Fixed by using srid 4326 for lng/lat points and then transforming to correct projection before search

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

p = GEOSGeometry("Point(-0.127907 51.507786)", srid=4326) # 4326 for standard lng/lat coordinates

# Transform to same coordinate system as maps
p.transform(27700)

RegionBorder.objects.filter(mpoly__contains=p)
[<RegionBorder: London>]
```